# After refresh I get old values in my page

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Hi, I have an inputText and a calendar component of primefaces in my page.

After entering some value, if I refresh the page, it shows my previously entered data.

How can I get blank inputText and resetted calendar after refresh?

```
<h:inputText value="#{myBean.name}"/>

<p:calendar value="#{myBean.date}"/>
```

By default I set calendar to current date from managed bean at initializing page. But at refresh time I get previously selected date which for my requirement should be current date.

P.S. I am using Liferay JSF Portlet

Comment: Make sure you're using a `@RequestScoped` bean and that you haven't submitted the data.

Comment: My page is viewscoped and I have also tried with request scoped it didnt work for me. :(

Comment: Isn't this just the browser builtin autocomplete? (easily to be confirmed by looking at generated HTML output, if the value is absent there, but present in the presentation, then it's definitely the browser's builtin autocomplete). Have you tried `autocomplete="off"` on the inputs?

Comment: @BalusC Ya it was due to autocomplete. Thanks its worked for me. Can you put this ans to in ans block so that I can select it as my accepted ans. Thanks :)

Comment: @BalusC What I have to do for selectonemenu? There is no autocomplete attribute for this component.

Comment: You need to provide SSCCE standard please

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem and it took me some time to fix it finding the disguised solution given by `@BalusC` in one of the above comments ten years ago.

`<p:calendar ... autocomplete="off" />`

It is not a problem of the Primefaces component but rather one of the browser behavior wanting to auto-complete formular fields.

Answer (score 0):

@LuiggiMendoza is correct. If you haven't submitted, then your bean is `@SessionScoped` or greater, but it needs to be `@ViewScoped` or less.

Comment: My page is viewscoped and I have also tried with request scoped it didnt work for me. :(

Comment: Please change your original post and add your code ([sscce](http://sscce.org) of course).

Comment: This problem exist with the simple code thats why I havent provided my code