# How to set autocomplete off for selectOneMenu?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Hi I need to turn autocomplete off for `selectOneMenu` of primefaces but there is no such attribute. We have this attribute in primefaces for `inputText` and for some other components.

How can I set autocomplete off or just get default value selected all time when user refresh the page.

I tried like this.

```
<p:selectOneMenu value="#{myBean.myVar}" autocomplete="off" id="selectMenu">
       <f:selectItems value="#{myBean.nameList}" var="cat"
                    itemLabel="#{cat.name}"
                    itemValue="#{cat.name}" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

P.S. I am using Liferay JSF Portlet

Please refer my ques--- [After refresh I get old values in my page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19227620/after-refresh-i-get-old-values-in-my-page)

I have checked this issue in IE and Chrome, it was working fine there. I am facing this problem only in Firefox.

Comment: Are you talking about a normal `selectOneMenu` or the one with filtering? If your value doesn't get cleared it's because you still have it in the managed bean...

Comment: its normal selectOneMenu. And I have tried it without any variable, I got same result

Comment: What browswer are you using? I suppose you tried with different browsers with different result. That never happened to me with FF and Chrome, not in selectonemenu. Also it would be grateful if you post a complete SSCCE and testable code.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a very old post but I got into this problem today and I think what I'm writing could be useful to somebody even if I'm using only JSF and not Primeface.

Using JSF 2.2 you can add attributes using the `<f:passThroughAttribute>` tag (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14935844/771431)).

In my case I had to put the attribute directly on the `h:form` element, because the browser (Chrome 48) seems to ignore `autocomplete` on the `select` element (maybe a Chrome bug?).

```
<h:form>
    <f:passThroughAttribute name="autocomplete" value="off" />
    ...
</h:form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that first you update or clear the **myBean.myVar** value when u refresh the page.
That will solve the problem.
and you will not get the default selected values.

Comment: Its already done. Actually whenever user refresh the page on managed bean init() method is called which initializes all values inclding myVar. Its due to browser autocomplete support

Comment: @KushSahu can you tell which browser are you using? Are you completely sure your `myVar` value is `null` when displaying it? Check it with a breakpoint in your getter method.

Comment: This is not due to browser auto complete need to have your managed Bean code here.

Comment: @XtremeBiker Ya I am sure. Also after removing all depenedency to managed bean its giving me same result

Comment: @BholaVishwakarma As I said in above comment I tried after removing my variable(myVar). Its giving me same result. Please refer my ques http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19227620/after-refresh-i-get-old-values-in-my-page and also please refer BalusC reply to that ques

Comment: Do u have team viewer 8 so i can just go through the code If u dont mine

Answer (score 0):

Is never too late xonya. That's the right answer:

Add:

```
HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse)
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getResponse();
response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store");
response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache"); // HTTP 1.0.
response.setDateHeader("Expires", 0); // Proxies.
```

And in XHTML add this to the h:form:

```
<h:form>
    <f:passThroughAttribute name="autocomplete" value="off" />
</h:form>
```

I had the Issue in Google Chrome.

Thanks again Xonya.